# How many necklaces can be made alternating between two colors and with a total to 10 different beads?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have 10 different beads. There are 5 white beads and 5 yellow beads (they are all different but may have the same color). How many necklaces can be made  such that the white and yellow appear alternatingly?
The correct answer is 1,440, but I have no idea of how to count the alternating pattern to get to this answer. This question comes from a section dealing with partitions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outline**

Consider the necklace as circular.
Fix one bead, say a particular white bead.  There are $4!$ arrangements for the remaining $4$ white beads and $5!$ arrangements for the remaining $5$ yellow beads.

Now because of flip symmetry we should divide the answer by $2$, so the total arrangements should be $\frac{4!5!}{2} = \color{blue}{1440}$